# Issue formatting html content fetched through Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using **Cordova tools** for **Visual Studio** to create a mobile app (windows 10, android). I'm using JQuery Ajax to get html content for a page ,the data response from this ajax call have some special characters like [\", \n, \t ,...].

**Sample :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <link type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"http://st.f1.video.vnecdn.net/i/v3/favicon.ico\" rel=\"shortcut icon\"/>\n        <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>\n                    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes\"/>\n                    <meta name=\"apple-mobile-web-app-capable\" content=\"yes\"/>\n
```

Hence I'm unable to convert it to jquery object : 
var dom = $(data);

I tried replacing them with empty string like below:

```
data = data.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '');
```

but it still contains character [\"]

==> please help me and sorry for my english

Comment: That looks like a chunk of JSON,  try decoding it.

Comment: i'm using jquery get menthod :
$.get(url, function(data) { var dom =$(data) }, 'html');

Answer (score 1):

'\' caracter is used to escape another character, so for escape the '\' you need to use '\'. I hope this may help you

Comment: how i can replace all [\"] character with ["] ?